# Python, Pandas to remove rows with specific value in designated columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

An Excel spreadsheet looked like below.

[image]

With Pandas, I want to remove the columns “Project C” and “Project E”, and all rows with value “XX” in Columns “Project A” and “Project D”.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

work_file = "C:\\test.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(work_file, sheetname = "Sheet1", index_col = 0)

column_list_to_remove = [“Project C", “Project E"]

results1 = df.drop(column_list_to_remove, axis=1)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("C:\\test new.xlsx")

pd.formats.format.header_style = None

results1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')

writer.save()
```

Above work well in removing the columns.

I try added on this line to remove rows with value “XX” in “Project A”, and failed. Without hope to remove those in “Project D”.

```
results1 = results1[results1."Project A" != "XX"]
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I remove those rows? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column names did not have whitespace, you could have done something along the lines of:

```
results1 = results1.query("ColumnName != 'XX'")
```

or alternatively inplace:

```
results1.query("ColumnName != 'XX'", inplace=True)
```

Alas, they do. Now you can either rename those columns, as whitespace is evil incarnate, or do:

```
results1 = results1[results1['Project A'] != 'XX']
```

Basically: create a mask for the index and slice the dataframe.

Renaming your columns without the whitespace can be done in a oneliner as well:

```
results1.columns = [''.join(x.strip().split()) for x in results1.columns]
```

Then you can proceed with something like:

```
column_list = ['ProjectA', 'ProjectD']
for col in column_list:
    results1.query(col+"!='XX'", inplace=True)
```

Comment: thank you. So if I don't want to rename the columns, I just need to repeat like results1 = results1[results1['Project D'] != 'XX'].

Comment: Yes; and of course you can put that in a loop or comprehension as well if you have a lot of these columns and you do not wish to copy paste the same line over and over.